# Why do python udp sockets open strange udp ports and how can I stop this?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, port

I'm having a strange problem with python udp sockets. When I send data over them, they open an udp port on 0.0.0.0 and I cannot find out why they do, what they do listen to and how to deactivate that behaviour. Our system administrators don't like ports to be listened on 0.0.0.0 (reasonably).

Minimum example:

```
import socket

fam = socket.AF_INET
family, _, _, _, addr = socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 9999, fam, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)[0]
sock = socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto('foobar'.encode('ascii'), addr)
```

Right after the last method call, the python program listens to:

```
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:41972  0.0.0.0:*  1000  308716  17777/python3
```

And this seems to stay until the python executable stops. So my question is, does anyone here have the same problem and how can I avoid it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What problem? This is what is supposed to happen. You didn't bind the socket so `sendto() performed a bind to 0.0.0.0:0 internally, and this is the result. The socket isn't 'listening', but it is bound. It will disappear when you close the socket. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Which port do you expect your packets to come from?

Sockets have ports at both ends. Packets come from a port and go to a port. You didn't pick a port (with `bind`), so the operating system chose one for you.

It's not a problem, it's how sockets work.

0.0.0.0 means "any IP address" by the way.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your really fast answer. I thought of anything like that, but I might have understood the concept of udp wrong: Isn't it independent of answers? So can I somehow say it to only listen to certain IPs?

Comment: @LukasWerner I believe can use `connect` to make it only listen to a certain IP and port.

Comment: `connect` seems to be for TCP. I can't find any way to say it to only listen on a specific IP. Are you sure, this is possible?

Comment: `connect` and `bind` are valid for both UDP and TCP; a "connected" UDP socket can be used with `send` instead of `sendto`.  e.g. see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

just to elaborate on my comment, here's how I'd put the socket calls together:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
  sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))  # optional
  sock.connect(('localhost', 9999))
  sock.send(b'foobar')
```

notes:

- `connect`ing a UDP socket should cause it to be bound to something more appropriate than `0.0.0.0`, and hence why I put an optional comment
- `getaddrinfo` doesn't help you much, hence I'm just passing names and letting Python resolve them internally
- using a name for the `connect` call and dotted-quad notation for `bind` looks a little strange. I'd suggest using just one format for consistency, or just using `connect` and not using `bind`

`getaddrinfo` is really useful when you want to be able to transparently handle IPv6 along with IPv4 addresses, especially for hosts that resolve to multiple addresses.  see the [Happy Eyeballs algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs) for an example

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found a workaround, even if I think it's not the cleanest way to do that, I couldn't find another one.

I used the method `bind(addr: tuple)` on the udp socket to make it listen to only a specific IP. In my case this looks like:

```
import socket

fam = socket.AF_INET
family, _, _, _, addr = socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 9999, fam, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)[0]
sock = socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))  # This is the new line where I bind only to 127.0.0.1
sock.sendto('foobar'.encode('ascii'), addr)
```

Thanks to @user253751 for leading me in the right direction.